# Assigns geographical locations to the pixels in isolate drone image in R

Tags: raster, r, rasterization, terra

In my example, I have a single dji image in *JPG:

```
library(terra)
single.image <-stack("https://github.com/Leprechault/trash/raw/main/DJI_0274.JPG")
plotRGB(single.image,  r = 3, g = 2, b = 1, stretch = "lin")
# class      : RasterStack 
# dimensions : 3648, 4864, 17743872, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
# resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
# extent     : 0, 4864, 0, 3648  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# crs        : NA 
# names      : DJI_0274_1, DJI_0274_2, DJI_0274_3
```

[image: testcanopy]

and the correspond Metadata in *jgw file:

```
single.image.mtd <- read.table("https://github.com/Leprechault/trash/raw/main/DJI_0274.jgw", header = FALSE, skip=1)
single.image.mtd
#              V1
# 1 -3.532000e-07
# 2  2.600000e-09
# 3  3.100000e-09
# 4  2.976000e-07
# 5 -5.170865e+01
# 6 -1.973617e+01
```

This values are:

```
# X-cell size
# rotation (usually 0)
# rotation (usually 0)
# Y-cell size (always negative)
# Upper left X
# Upper left Y
```

How is it possible to use the metadata in order to have a georeferenced image and save it in GeoTIFF format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JGW file looks like a standard "sidecar" "world file" for describing an image location, this should be understood by a driver in the GDAL library which is used by R packages such as `terra` and `raster`. My only concern is your `skip=1` parameter which makes me think there's an initial line. My image world files seem to only have six lines. Here's one:

```
3.54701036838847461
0 
0 
-3.54701036838847461
4042209.18287775944918394
3803207.26590952137485147
```

When I read the accompanying `heatmap.jpg` file in `terra` it gets located correctly because `terra::rast` uses `GDAL` and `GDAL` looks at the sidecar file and tells `terra` what the coordinates are:

```
> library(terra)
terra 1.6.18
> hm = rast("./heatmap.jpg")
> hm
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 740, 851, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 3.54701, 3.54701  (x, y)
extent      : 4042207, 4045226, 3800584, 3803209  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
[etc]
```

You could then use `writeRaster` to write this as a GeoTIFF file.

The only thing missing to locate this geographically is the coordinate system that the numbers in your `.jgw` file are using. Possibly these are lat-long degrees - was the image taken at 51S and 19W? That would put it in the south Atlantic...

Comment: Coordinates are rather 51.x° W and 19.x° S.. ;-)